# Sign In/Up Form in different migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I have a devise users table with a fully functioning sign in/up form.

What I was wondering was how to have that users form appear on a different table.

For example

users/sign_in works perfectly
but 
I want to have that form appear on movies/index

Ive tried adding the form code to the movies/index but i get this error

```
undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#<Class:0x00000102cbf0b8>:0x00000103bb6d78>
```

This is the sign in form

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f|     %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This solved my answer http://pupeno.com/2010/08/29/show-a-devise-log-in-form-in-another-page/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the views (I understand you already did that) and you can override the controllers, or, in your case, you can watch the controllers of Devise, take the code that you need, and in your view call a partial (from the Devise views).

I did something like that a few months ago, but what I did (that I don't fully suggest but I haven't find a better way) was to  take the code from the Devise views, and copy the code in another view with some modifications:

```
<%= form_for(User.new, :as => "user", :url => session_path("user"), :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" , :class=>"blue_submit_degradiant", :id =>"sign_in_user"%></div>
<% end %>
```

It works, but the right way is to have a @user instead of User.new